# Change the background only when the list is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to make it so that when the filter list is empty, change the background to one color, but when there is something in the list, to keep it the same?

```js
$('#myInput').keyup(function(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 13){
  mySearch();
  Check();
 }
});
  
function myInput()  {  
 var empt = document.getElementById("myInput").value;  
 if (empt == "")  
 {  
  mySearch();
  return false;  
 }  
 else   
 {   
  return true;   
 }  
}
  
function mySearch() {
 var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
 input = document.getElementById("myInput");
 filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
 ul = document.getElementById("myUl");
 li = ul.getElementsByTagName("a");
 for (tag = 0; tag < li.length; tag++) {
  a = li[tag].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
  if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
     li[tag].style.display = "";
  } else {
   li[tag].style.display = "none";
  }
 }
}
```

```css
#listentry {
 width: 280px;
 height: 150px;
 color: #999;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 background-color: #1d1d1d;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #0d0d0d;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
 border-top-left-radius: 6px;
} 
#listentry:hover {
 background-color: #222;
 color: #999;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myInput()" placeholder="Search...">
<div id="myUl">
  <a href="#indexModal" id="entry">
   <article id="listentry">
    <img src="Images/index.png" id="img1" style="float: left; width: 105px; height: 150px;">
    <article id="desc">
     <center>
        <p id="title">A Certain Magical Index</p>
      <p id="rating">TV-MA</p>
     </center>
    </article>
   </article>
  </a>
  <a href="#index2Modal">
   <article id="listentry">
       <img src="Images/index2.png" id="img1" style="float: left; width: 105px; height: 150px;">
       <article id="desc">
     <center>
      <p id="title4">A Certain Magical Index: The Miracle of Endymion</p>
      <p id="rating">TV-MA</p>
     </center>
    </article>
   </article>
  </a>
  <a href="#railgunModal">
   <article id="listentry">
       <img src="Images/railgun.png" id="img1" style="float: left; width: 104px; height: 150px;">
    <article id="desc">
     <center>
      <p id="title">A Certain Scientific Railgun</p>
      <p id="rating">TV-14</p>
     </center>
    </article>
   </article>
  </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm looking for a way so that when something is filtered and still visible, the background stays the same, but when the filter list can't find anything to change the background.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using a conditional statement which scans your list to see for values. If the list is empty, you can change the background color:

```
count = 0            //initializes a variable to count the number of items in the list
for(var x in list){  //Loops through your "list" to find items
    count += 1;      //If an item is found, the variable count increments
}
if(count < 1){       //If there is NOT any items in your list (empty)...
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";  //Then change the background color
}
else{
    <!--pass-->  //Do what you like.
}
```

Hope this is what your looking for.